# Generating a word file using template with php on Linux Server

Tags: php, linux

Please let me know if you know a word file generator for php on Linux server.

I have a template word file and I want to generate a word file according to the template using php from my linux webserver.

As far as I can find on the web, all of these php libraries need Microsoft Word application to install on the server. I need plug-in which doesn't need to install word in the webserver since mine is linux. Please guide me.

Any work around or name of the plug-in would help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment you can use You can use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord It's a PHP library that can create DOCX along with some formatting.

If you are looking for a similar solution you can also visit this link

http://webcheatsheet.com/php/create_word_excel_csv_files_with_php.php